# R: String character vector using logical OR | to sprintf time interval

Tags: r, string, printf, logic, intervals

I am trying to create a vector of hours with intervals of 20 minutes, from 09:00 am to 15:40, like so:

```
09:00, 09:20, 09:40, 10:00, 10:20... 15:00, 15:20, 15:40.
```

and I am using sprintf command.

If I use

```
sprintf("%02d:00", c(09.00:15.00))
```

I get

```
[1] "09:00" "10:00" "11:00" "12:00" "13:00" "14:00" "15:00"
```

Which I used for a previous ggplot graph, and was successful, although I'm still learning how to use it.

However, I thought I could use something like

```
sprintf("%02d:00"|"%02d:20", c(09.20:15.40))
```

to obtain

```
[1] "09:20" "10:00" "10:20" "11:00" "11:20"... "14:00" "14:20" "15:00" "15:20"
```

but I know I can't, it's not a numerical value. I wonder why is there not a way around this, instead of a totally different and easier code. If I made it here is because my mind is stuck on thinking about this code, and although I would appreciate a working code, I really want to see if I am not too lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps not as short, but this makes use of the fact that you're actually working with date/time values here and they do not behave like regular numeric sequences

```
strftime(seq(
  as.POSIXct("2014-01-01 9:20:00"), 
  as.POSIXct("2014-01-01 15:40:00"), by="20 min")
, "%H:%M")

#  [1] "09:20" "09:40" "10:00" "10:20" "10:40" "11:00" "11:20" "11:40" "12:00"
# [10] "12:20" "12:40" "13:00" "13:20" "13:40" "14:00" "14:20" "14:40" "15:00"
# [19] "15:20" "15:40"
```

Comment: I am still confused about POSIXct objetcs. It is claimed I could mix them with data and multiply them or add and substract time, but at the same time, they are restricted for being strings. Am I wrong?
Thanks for the quick response, MrFlick. :)

Comment: POSIXct are not strings at all. strftime formats POSIXct values are strings. They are special objects that store the number of seconds since a particular event and have overloaded methods to do some basic arithmetic. You could read the `?DateTimeClasses` help page for more info.